# Error:Call to a member function create() on null , unit test (Mockery)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to unit test "**AdminService**" class that has "**create()**" method and in the constructor I need a dependency which is **AdminRepository**.

I used mockery to mock the repository and passed this mock to AdminService _contsruct() but i got and error when i run the test that says: Error: **Call to a member function create() on null**

This is the **AdminService** that I'm trying to test  :
I followed this article : [Unit tests – complex argument matching with Mockery::on – the right way](https://laradevtips.com/2018/12/01/unit-tests-complex-argument-matching-with-mockeryon-the-right-way/)

```
use App\Repositories\AdminRepository;

class AdminService {

    protected $admin_repo;

    public function _contsruct(AdminRepository $admin_repo){
        $this->$admin_repo= $admin_repo;
    }

    public function create($data){
        return  $this->admin_repo->create($data); 

    }



}
```

and the test code is :

```
/** @test */
   public function it_can_create_Admin(){

      $data=[
         "first_name"=>"lama",
         "last_name"=>"sonmez",
         "email"=>"lamasonmez@gmail.com",
         "password"=>"secret"
      ];


      $repo_mock = Mockery::mock(AdminRepository::class);
      $repo_mock->shouldReceive('create')->once()->with($data)
          ->andReturn('anything');
      $admin_service = new AdminService($repo_mock);
      $admin = $admin_service->create($data);
      $this->assertInstanceOf(Admin::class,$admin);

   }
```

I don't know what's wrong here , please help.

when I dd($repo_mock) is gives me the mock I mean it's not null
but when I dd($admin_service) I got

```
App\Services\AdminService^ {#4106
  #admin_repo: null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh I figured out why this happens, this was because of the underscore sign for the constructors in AdminRepository and AdminService it should have two underscores before the construct keywork like this **__construct**  and not like this **_construct**